# What is the use of pagebuilder.widget.initializer on frontend

Tags: magento2, theme, page-builder

> vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

I have checked the above file and see

```
  <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\PageBuilder\Block\GoogleMapsApi" name="google.maps.api" template="Magento_PageBuilder::googlemaps.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\PageBuilder\Block\WidgetInitializer" name="pagebuilder.widget.initializer" template="Magento_PageBuilder::widget_initializer.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Can you clarify more what you mean by this?

Comment: @brentwpeterson what is the use of pagebuilder.widget.initializer on frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A storefront widget is a JavaScript component that handles the
>   behavior of a content type after Page Builder renders it on the
>   storefront. For example, the Tabs and Sliders have their own
>   storefront widgets to handle the end-user’s tapping of tabs and
>   swiping of slides on the storefront.

You can use this to specify places in which you want to insert page builder elements

https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/how-to/how-to-add-storefront-widget.html

Comment: Thanks !!! Do you have any example module which  you have used widget at storefront?

Comment: You can create your own widgets in the backend and use pagebuilder. You don't need a module